# I'm getting the error "Please install clang or check configuration"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10.  I installed VSC and so far happier than when I was on Eclipse, but have hit a snag.

I'm trying to include a .h file, but getting an error WiFi.h not found.  I've got the "includePath" set to include this file location, but still getting that error, along with the "Please install clang...".  Well, I had already installed it (C/C++ Clang Command Adapter 0.2.2, and Clang-Format 1.6.1" via the extensions 'install'.  I checked and I have a directory ""clang-format.executable": "~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.16.1/LLVM/bin/clang-format" on my system.  So, the research I had done indicated I should either change the PATH, which I did, but that didn't solve it.  I also edited the 'user settings', and set: ""clang-format.executable": "~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.16.1/LLVM/bin/clang-format", but I'm still getting the problem.

I don't understand why VSC isn't finding the include!

Any help would be appreciated.  I've restarted VSC to make sure that wasn't an issue, and also did a 'app-clean', but still the error.

[edit-add]: the include is outside of the project I'm working on, but so are some of the other include .h files, so I don't think this makes any difference....

Thanks!

Comment: I installed LLVM using this youtube as guidance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ffOxJrHKDk

Comment: I did the clang-6.0 test.c -o test_ccode per that video, and got the successful "Hello World", so that appears to be working.  Restarting VSC and selecting 'build task' gives the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: In "user settings, I added (which may be wrong, but that's what I think I'm supposed to do from earlier research...), after doing "whereis clang-6.0 and getting the path: "clang.executable": "/usr/bin/clang-6.0", but again, no joy!